# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method in database seeder in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, factory

I have errors executing the command::

```
>php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

The error message is:

```
 BadMethodCallException

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Diary::diarySubjob()

  at C:\MAMP\htdocs\dominios\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:50
     46▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     47▕      */
     48▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     49▕     {
  ➜  50▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     51▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     52▕         ));
     53▕     }
     54▕ }

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\Diary::subjobs() ?

  1   C:\MAMP\htdocs\dominios\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:36
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException()

  2   C:\MAMP\htdocs\dominios\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1993
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo()
```

**Class DiarySubJob**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class DiarySubjob extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'diary_id',
        'work_id',
        'subjob_id',
        'company',
        'customer',
        'repair',
        'duration',
        'observations',
    ];

    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = true;

    
    /** 
     * Partidas de un diario.
     */
    public function subjobs()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Subjob::class);
    }


    /**
     * Diarios de una partida.
     */
    public function diaries()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Diary::class);
    }

    /**
     * Obras o clientes de una partida.
     */
    public function works()
    {
        $this->belongsTo(Work::class);
    }
}
```

**Class Diary**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Diary extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'observations',
        'duration',
        'overtime'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'observations'  => 'string',
    ];

    /**
     * Obtener el usuario/empleado de un diario.
     */ 
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /** 
     * Obtener las partidas de un parte diario.
     */
    public function subjobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subjob::class)->using(DiarySubjob::class);
    }
}
```

**Class Subjob**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subjob extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_id',
        'name'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name'      => 'string'
    ];

    /** 
     * Obtener el trabajo/partida al que pertenece este subtrabajo/subpartida.
     */
    public function job()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Job::class);
    }

    /**
     * Partes de trabajo diarios de la partida.
     */
    public function diaries()
    {
        $this->belogsToMany(Diary::class)->using(DiarySubjob::class);
    }
}
```

**Class DiarySubjobFactory**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\DiarySubjob;
use App\Models\Diary;
use App\Models\Subjob;
use App\Models\Work;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class DiarySubjobFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = DiarySubjob::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'diary_id' => DiarySubjob::diaries()->all()->random()->id,
            'work_id' => Work::all()->random()->id,
            'subjob_id' => Subjob::all()->random()->id,            
            'company' => $this->faker->company(),
            'repair' => $this->faker->boolean(),
            'duration' => '02:00:00',
            'overtime' => '00:00:00',
            'observations' => $this->faker->realText(255, 2)
        ];
    }
}
```

**Class DatabaseSeeder**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Work::factory(5)->create();

        $this->call([
            JobSeeder::class,
            SubJobSeeder::class,
            ConfigurationSeeder::class
        ]);

        \App\Models\User::factory(20)
            ->has(\App\Models\Salary::factory(1))
            ->has(\App\Models\Diary::factory(10))            
            ->create();

        \App\Models\Diary::factory(1)
            ->has(\App\Models\DiarySubjob::factory(15))
            ->create();
    }
}
```

The error when this line is executed:

```
\App\Models\Diary::factory(1)
            ->has(\App\Models\DiarySubjob::factory(15))
            ->create();
```

To be more concise, I get the error running this:

```
->has(\App\Models\DiarySubjob::factory(15))
```

It tells me that I am calling a method that is not defined **App\Models\Diary::diarySubjob()** and it advises me to call the method **App\Models\Diary::subjobs()** But nowhere do I call the method **App\Models\Diary::diarySubjob()**

What can this error be due to? I am very lost. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you did not read the documentation, as it clearly says that it is related to the relation's name convention that Laravel uses.

Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#has-many-relationships) part of the documentation.

So, your solution would be to replace the part you know is giving error with:

```php
\App\Models\Diary::factory(1)
    ->has(\App\Models\DiarySubjob::factory(15), 'subjobs')
    ->create();
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I apologize for a billion, sir. Thanks for the prompt response and your solution. Being Spanish, the subject of the Anglo-Saxon nomenclature sometimes complicates my work. And as for the documentation, I read it, or I try to read and understand it, but this time I was left in the dark and although I had it in front of me, I could not find my error. Again, I apologize sir and I am very grateful for your time. It saved my life.